# Why the CATransaction setCompletionBlock is delayed after the animation duration

Tags: ios, animation, swift, core-animation

I'm trying to practice the `CATransaction` and `CABasicAnimation` with `CAShapeLayer`, I got the animation work perfectly as I wanted, but the animation finished block was not called immediately after the animation is finished.

### code

Here is the key piece of code that I use:

```
func startAnimation(){
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(10.0)
    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    pathAnimation.duration = 10.0
    pathAnimation.fromValue = 0.0 as NSNumber
    pathAnimation.toValue = 1.0 as NSNumber

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
        NSLog("finished")
    }
    pathLayer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    self.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
    CATransaction.commit()
    NSLog("start")
}
```

### Output

The output from 2 NSLog looks like this:

```
2015-01-14 00:30:05.549 QuartzCorePlayground[47369:2769473] start
2015-01-14 00:30:22.004 QuartzCorePlayground[47369:2769473] finished
```

### <del>Question</del> Got the Answer

> Why does `finished` always be printed about 6.5s later after the animation is finished? Where is wrong in my code?

#### ANSWER

The reason is, as mentioned in the comment, **it looks like to be a bug in the Xcode playground**, when I put the code in real project it runs as my understanding of CoreAnimation.

---

#### Full playgroud code

Here is the full code that I'm running in Xcode playground(you need to check the **`Run in Full Simulator`** option in Xcode)

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import XCPlayground

func radians(degree : CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat((Double(degree) / 180) * M_PI)
}

class TimerShapeView : UIView {

    var pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let innerSize : CGFloat = 20
        var squareRectSize = min(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))
        var squareRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - squareRectSize)/2 + innerSize, (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - squareRectSize)/2 + innerSize)

        let workoutPath = UIBezierPath()
        workoutPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(squareRect), y: CGRectGetMidY(squareRect)), radius: CGRectGetWidth(squareRect)/2, startAngle: radians(90), endAngle: radians(360), clockwise: true)

        pathLayer.frame = self.bounds
        pathLayer.path = workoutPath.CGPath
        pathLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
        pathLayer.geometryFlipped = true
        pathLayer.fillColor = nil
        pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel

        self.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func startAnimation(){
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(10.0)
        let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        pathAnimation.duration = 10.0
        pathAnimation.fromValue = 0.0 as NSNumber
        pathAnimation.toValue = 1.0 as NSNumber

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
            NSLog("finished")
        }
        pathLayer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
        self.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
        CATransaction.commit()
        NSLog("start")
    }

}

var shapeTimerView = TimerShapeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 220))
XCPShowView("newTimerView", shapeTimerView)

shapeTimerView.startAnimation()
```

Comment: Did you try it in an actual project other than playground? I am not getting the delay inside the project.

Comment: @rakeshbs you're right. I can confirm that it's a Playground bug. When I put the code in real project, it works fine. Thanks